# Sending command to Bluetooth LE Device from a iOS App

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm building a simple IOS app for interacting with a Bluetooth LE device.

Main steps ( Connecting, discovering services, discovering characteristics and reading characteristics' values ) are done rightly.

Now i'm searching for a tutorial/example for **sending** **command** to the Bluetooth LE device i'm connected on.

I'm searching in the Apple Developer Guide but i'm not finding anything.

Comment: You need to write on characteristics and the device it self has to know what to do when its characteristic value has been changed.

Comment: The device knows that when characteristic value has been changed it must write to output a list of numbers. Do i have to know some device documentation about reading this output or can i just wait for the output ? And how con i read this output?

Comment: It depends on how it works. For example, it could use notify on another characteristic (that you need to register the notify), or if it supports the writeWithResponse, once you know that your data has been written, you can start reading the other characteristic.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? If so, please post your answer to help other people for the same.

Comment: Not yet . I used the SDK of the Bluetooth Device so i didn't use the a general command because it's not compatible with it.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Apple's [TemperatureSensor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html) example, specifically where it calls `[servicePeripheral writeValue:data ...`

Answer (score 1):

When interacting with a `CBCharacteristic` I am going to assume it is a read/write characteristic (you can confirm this by looking at the value for `properties` on your characteristic).

The two main methods when interacting with a characteristic are:

```
func writeValue(_ data: NSData!, forCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, type type: CBCharacteristicWriteType)
func readValueForCharacteristic(_ characteristic: CBCharacteristic!)
```

Both of these methods are found on your `CBPeripheral`. Once you have called one of these functions you can utilize the `CBPeripheralDelegate` to confirm each of these actions in these `delegate` methods:

```
optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error error: NSError!)
optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error error: NSError!)
```

These are the places you will look to confirm your read and write's success. (inside of your read you can retrieve the value that was read from the BLE Device off the `value` property on `CBCharacteristic`.

Keep in mind the interactions you have (what you can read and write) are entirely dependent on the BLE device you are interrogating/interacting with. Essentially you must know what to read, what to write, and how.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a data with [`writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:) method of CBPeripheral. What characteristic+data match the required commands must be described in device specification.

Comment: Your insight is clear, but how can i read the output of the characteristic?